# Docker bind-mount not working as expected within AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I have created the following `Dockerfile` to run a spring-boot app: `myapp` within an EC2 instance.

```
# Use an official java runtime as a parent image
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine


# Add a user to run our application so that it doesn't need to run as root
RUN adduser -D -s /bin/sh myapp


# Set the current working directory to /home/myapp
WORKDIR /home/myapp

#copy the app to be deployed in the container
ADD target/myapp.jar myapp.jar

#create a file entrypoint-dos.sh and put the project entrypoint.sh content in it
ADD entrypoint.sh entrypoint-dos.sh

#Get rid of windows characters and put the result in a new entrypoint.sh in the container
RUN sed -e 's/\r$//' entrypoint-dos.sh > entrypoint.sh

#set the file as an executable and set myapp as the owner
RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh && chown myapp:myapp entrypoint.sh

#set the user to use when running the image to myapp
USER myapp

# Make port 9010 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 9010


ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Because I need to access `myapp`'s logs from the EC2 host machine, i want to bind-mount a folder into the logs folder sitting  within "myapp" container here: `/home/myapp/logs`

This is the command that i use to run the image in the ec2 console:

```
docker run -p 8090:9010 --name myapp myapp:latest -v home/ec2-user/myapp:/home/myapp/logs
```

The container starts without any issues, but the mount is not achieved as noticed in the following `docker inspect` extract:

```
...      
"Mounts": [],
...
```

I have tried the followings actions but ended up with the same result:

- `--mount type=bind` instead of `-v`
- use volumes instead of bind-mount
- I have even tried the `--privileged` option
- In the Dockerfile: I tried to use the `USER root` instead of `myapp`

I believe that, this has nothing to do with the ec2 machine but my container. Since running other containers with bind-mounts on the same host works like a charm.

I am pretty sure i am messing up with my Dockerfile.

But what am i doing wrong in that Dockerfile ?

or

What am i missing out ?

Here you have the `entrypoint.sh` if needed:

```
   #!/bin/sh
   echo "The app is starting ..."
   exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom  -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILES} "${HOME}/myapp.jar" "$@"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be the order of the options on the command line. Docker expects the last two arguments to be the image id/name and (optionally) a command/args to run as pid 1.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

> The basic docker run command takes this form:
>   $ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]

You have the mount options (-v in the example you provided) after the image name (myall:latest). I'm not sure but perhaps the `-v ...` is being interpreted as arguments to be passed to your entrypoint script (which are being ignored) and `docker run` isn't seeing as a mount option.

Also, the source of the mount here (home/ec2-user/myapp) doesn't start with a leading forward slash (/), which, I believe, will make it relative to where the `docker run` command is executed from. You should make sure the source path starts with a forward slash (i.e. /home/ec2-user/myapp) so that you're sure it will always mount the directory you expect. I.e. `-v /home/ec2-user...`

Have you tried this order:

`docker run -p 8090:9010 --name myapp -v /home/ec2-user/myapp:/home/myapp/logs myapp:latest`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The forgotten leading slash is just a typo when I was editing the question.  However you are totally right about the order. I should have pay attention more carefully to the synopsis. I will try that ASAP.